# Rebuilding Grpc.Core nuget locally for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, grpc

I'm attempting to use gRPC in my Xamarin.iOS project in order to use the Embedded Assistant API. I have two issues:

1) I can't create a Channel from an access token (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18178)

2) I need the native ext library to support armv7

I can use the workaround for (1) described in the link for now, and for (2) I can add armv7 to build_native_ext_for_ios.sh and rebuild fine.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to either create the nuget again or otherwise reference the newly updated libraries.

I tried running through some of the python scripts to generate artifacts, but continue to run into errors in task_runner.py (can't use + for concatenating dicts, can't compare NoneType and str, etc).

Comment: You can just create use `dotnet pack` but create the nuget, but you'll first need to add put the pre-compiled native libraries (you can grab them from an existing nuget package) in the right path as required by the Grpc.Core.csproj - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5fb10c194999b9fb8bb5b2e78d2fd7418fd894f1/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Grpc.Core.csproj#L35. Once you do that, you can just create the nupkg normally, without needing to use our internal build scripts at all.

Comment: @JanTattermusch Thanks. I can rebuild the nuget now. The only issue I'm seeing now is that, while generating an armv7-compatible (and iOS 10 compatible) native library, the libgrpc.a being produced is missing symbols (a few example obj files it's missing are a_bitstr.o and a_enum.o, along with many others). I'm using a  build_native_ext_for_ios.sh modified to include armv7 and to set the min ios version.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/18324 has been submitted.